# How to fix the offset when jquery-ui set center align element draggable?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

here's the vertical center align element draggable [example](https://codepen.io/tp1415926535/pen/oNaOePX):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #draggablediv {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: yellow;

            position: absolute;
            margin: auto 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="draggablediv"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#draggablediv").draggable();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Because of "margin: auto", the draggable element will no longer set the top value accurately. Is there a way to get it to work properly?

Comment: hello, what causes the problem is not the margin, instead it's `position: absolute`, through [this doc](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and by investigating its code, I see the position is set to `position: relative` (you can use DevTools to see the div css rules

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez However, I need an element that is vertically centered in the body and hovering over the interface, so setting it to relative is not what I want.

Comment: I really did not understand your point (sorry), maybe if you can share the full code so I can give you more suggestions ? or if you use for that [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can play around your code ?

Comment: Well, Maybe you wanted to say that the draggable element should be translated/moves vertically only in the center of the page ? (you can correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez Well, I provided a codepen hyperlink in my description. First I need a hover element with an initial state that is vertically centered. But at present it is normal to drag left or right, but dragging top or bottom will cause an offset. I need it to follow the correct position of the mouse when dragging to top or bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue can be fixed into two steps:

- To Initially center your element veritically, I would suggest to use FlexBox that way:

```css
/* to make sure that both document root & body take the whole vertical space */
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

- To fix the top/bottom wrong offset, you should remove

```css
#draggablediv {
  ... 
  ... 
  /* remove these 2 lines:*/
  top: 0; /* <--- this */
  bottom: 0; /* <--- this */
  ...
}
```

This is **one of many suggestions**, another suggestion (in case you don't want to touch body & document root) you may use another parent div container to apply the same previous rules or to center your element using JQuery also.